# Returning a reference to *this, from an anonymous object on stack

Tags: c++

Suppose the class `Coord3D` has a method

```
Point2D& Coord3D::get2DPart(){
    return *(Point2D*)this;
}
```

(Coord3D is just int x; int y; int z;, and Point2D is the 2D version of it with exactly int x; and int y;)

Would the following be safe:

```
Point2D x = Coord3D(1,2,3).get2DPart();
```

Or even something like

```
Coord3D x = Coord3D(1,2,3).getSelf();
```

where `getSelf()` is a function which does `return *this;`

Seems like it'll probably be safe, but people I asked aren't sure about it. Is this OK?

**Edit:** this is what coord3D and Point2D are:

```
struct Coord3D{
   float x; float y; float z;
};
struct Point2D{
   float x; float y;
};
```

Comment: Are `Coord3D` and `Point2D` related? (i.e. directly or not, `class Coord3D: public Point2D {}`?)

Comment: They're actuall structs, editing to add what they are

Comment: Still, are they related? If they are not, the cast is invalid.

Comment: I guess they're not, but if the actual contents of the class is the same, don't inherit from any other class, and have no virtual functions, it seems like it would be safe? I have static asserts in place to make sure they're always the same expected size.

Comment: I'll probably work, but it's not valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Point2D x = Coord3D(1,2,3).get2DPart();`

is equivalent to:

`Point2D x( Coord3D(1,2,3).get2DPart() );`

The temporary `Coord3D` you create here will last as long as `Point2D`'s constructor is being executed. Therefore, using `Coord3D`'a `this` in that scope is safe.

Note that `*(Point2D*)this` smells. If `Point3D` inherits from `Point2D`, you can just return `*this`. If they are unrelated, it's dangerous.

---

Edit, following the question's update regarding the types:

Given Point2D and Point3D are not related, casting one into the other might work, but it's highly unadvised. A better approach would be to have Point3D inherit from Point2D. Another option would be to add, say, a `GetPoint2D()` to `Point3D`, and have it *create* a new 2D point out of the 3D. However, you might have then a real issue with returning references to local variables. Lastly, if you do take the risk and cast as is, at least use `reinterpret_cast` and not the C-style cast.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the cast is valid in the first place (common subsequence of a standard layout type or whatever applies in your case), then yes this is valid as `*this` will live until `;`.